# knitr: local function cannot be found when converting markdown file into html

Tags: r, knitr, rhtml

Hi I am using R studio and the "knitHTML" button to convert my Rmd file into a html file. However, even thought the code runs fine, when using knitHTML it cannot find any of my local function  created:

**Error:Couldnot find function "xxx" calls:...withCallingHandlers->withVisible->eval->eval->corr**

Comment: Do you use the cache function from knitr? if so you have to make sure that your functions are in a chunk that is always evaluated (in chunk options set `cache=FALSE`) and not just stored away in a cache.

Comment: @SarinaJ,i firgured out later using **knit2html("source_file")** function on command line  is correctly using the local function rather than knit html tab. 'll try alternative you suggested n 'll let you know.

Comment: Was this ever solved?

Comment: Hi @Sarina ! Your suggestion did it for me. I think your's should be the answer to this question.